# best training methods for binary text classification using doc2vec gensim

Tags: machine-learning, gensim, doc2vec

I am trying to use doc2vec to do text classification based on document subject, for example, I want to classify all documents about sports as 1 and all other documents as 0. I want to do this by first training a doc2vec model with training data and then use a classification model such as logistic regression to classify the texts as positive or negative.

I have seen various examples online to do this [[1](https://fzr72725.github.io/2018/01/14/genism-guide.html),[2](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-doc2vec-logistic-regression-9da9947b43f4)] which employ different methods and I am unclear about some of the details as to why they are using certain methods, and which method is the best for text classification.

1. Firstly Using the example above, is it better to train the model using just documents related to sports or documents on all subjects. My thinking was by training just on sports documents you could classify documents based on document similarity(although this wouldnt produce vectors for non sports documents to use to train the next model). Also, i feel like if training the model on all documents you would need a huge amount of documents to represent everything other than sports to get good classification.
2. Secondly, which features are actually used to train the logistic regression model. If training the model on all documents I assume you would track the documents using an index of some sort and then train the logistic regression model using the vectors with a class label, is this correct ?
3. Thirdly, I have seen various uses of TaggedDocument where a unique id is put for each document and also where a shared id is used to represent the same class, eg., 1 = sports 0 = non sports. From what I have read a shared id means the model has a single vector representing each class, while using a unique id provides unique vectors for each document, is this correct ?. If so, assuming that I need unique labeled vectors for training the logistic regression model what is the point of using a shared id ? Wouldnt this provide terrible classification results ?

If anyone can help me with the questions above and generally what is the best way to do text classification using doc2vec vectors it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did it go in the end? I am doing a very similar project at the moment, I am trying to determine whether a NDA form is valid or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an example included in `gensim` of using `Doc2Vec` for sentiment-classification, very close to your need. See:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/bcee414663bdcbdf6a58684531ee69c6949550bf/docs/src/gallery/howtos/run_doc2vec_imdb.py

(It's likely a better model than the other tutorials you link. In particular, the [second tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-doc2vec-logistic-regression-9da9947b43f4) you've linked currently has a very erroneous mismanagement of `alpha` in its misguided loop calling `train()` multiple times.)

Specifically with regard to your questions:

(1) Train with as much data, both inside and outside the desired class, as possible. A model that's only seen "positive" examples is unlikely to generate meaningful vectors from documents totally unlike those it's been trained on. (In particular, with a model like `Doc2Vec`, it only knows words it's seen during training, and if you later try to infer vectors for new documents with unknown words, those words are ignored entirely.)

(2) Yes, a classifier (of any algorithm) is fed features *and* known-labels. It then learns to deduce those labels from those features.

(3) Traditionally, `Doc2Vec` is trained with one unique ID 'tag' per document – and no known-label information. So, each document gets its own vector, and the process is totally "unsupervised". It's possible to instead give documents multiple tags, or use the same tag on more than one document. And, you could make those tags match known-labels – so all "sports" docs share `'sports'` tag (either in addition to their unique-ID, or instead of it). But, doing this adds a number of other complications over the simple, one-ID-tag-per-document, case. So I wouldn't recommend trying anything in that direction until you've got the simpler case working. (I have seen a few cases where mixing in known-labels as extra tags can help a little, especially in multi-class classification issues, where such extra labels each only apply to a small subset of all documents. But it's not assured – and thus only makes sense to tinker with that after you have a working straightforward baseline, and repeatable way to evaluate alternate models against each other.)

Comment: One question about using elements from across different classes. When creating document/paragraph vectors apart from the word vector matrix does the doc2vec use any other information that is always the same?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The only input to the `Doc2Vec` training is texts (lists of word-tokens), which also have one or more `tags` (most often a single unique ID). The only other info that is "always the same" (across the model training) is the choice of model meta-parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was talking about the inner-working of doc2vec based on this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.4053 . Doc2vec constructs a word vector matrix which is used for constructing document representations. The reason I was asking is because I plan on training the model on several documents, however I plan to use it on documents with great variance in length. So I don't know if I should Train more doc2vec models(for the variable length) or use the same one for all the documents of variable length.

Comment: A word-vector matrix similar to that in word2vec is a feature of some 'Paragraph Vector' modes, but not all. (Plain "PV-DBOW" doesn't create word-vectors, and even the "PV-DM" mode trains the word-vectors simultaneous with, not as a 1st step before, doc-vector training.) I've not seen any good writeups on effect-of-doc-length on `Doc2Vec` models. My rough sense is that the doc-vectors work best representing texts of dozens to hundreds (or low-thousands) of words, but you might find something different for other corpuses or purposes.

Comment: You *can* feed wildly different doc-sizes to a single model, but small docs (dominated by a few words) might tend to have more distinctive representations, and the fact that the number of training-updates a doc-vector gets is a function of the word count in its document could mean larger docs essentially dominate training-attention, with unclear effects. But, if docs are separated into separate models, the model output vectors won't be comparable, as there's no one universal coordinate-space - each is just for the co-trained documents, in that particular intialization/run.

Comment: If short-vs-long documents are of equal importance, you could experiment with things like oversampling shorter documents - such as repeating their texts to be as long as other documents.

Comment: Thank you. If I build two model, I don't intend on directly comparing their them. The short texts will be compared to short texts only. Therefore I shall try the two model approach as well as a one model approach.

Comment: I tested the two approaches by assessing their scores of self-similarity. I found that training the short texts alone brings worse results, because there is less material to train if I only include the short texts. I need to still compare corpora that have basically the same amount of material and one is divided into short texts and one into longer ones.

Comment: If a model seems much worse than another based solely on whether re-inferred vectors are similar to the same bulk-training vectors, that could (1) be indicative of other issues in model/data size/parameters; (2) be very influenced by different modes/etc. For example, you might want to think of the doc-vectors in terms of *how much training attention* they each got. 1 million total words, 10 equal-sized documents, 10 epochs would mean every doc-vector is adjusted (100,000 words * 10 epochs) 1 million times in the iterative predict/adjust/repeat training process.  …

Comment: But 1 million total words, 1000 documents, 10 epochs would mean each doc-vector only adjusted 10,000 times. At a top level, it seems like you're performing the same amount of training, but that training has to tune-up 100X more end-products, so its influence is diluted, and those 1000 doc-vectors won't be as 'tuned' to their respective texts.

Comment: Interesting. You are right I reduced the number of epochs to reduce the amount calculation. I have now also tried to compare corpora(shorter texts vs longer) with same amount of words altogether. There results on self-similarity are basically the same.